# Why is my store procedure throwing a syntax error

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a MySql database (statements) that contains a table (trans). I have written a stored procedure but I am getting a syntax error that I don't understand.   The stored procedure is supposed to go through the trans table and assign a category (WorkSheetCatCodeTest) based upon several conditions that are contained in a case statement.

The error that I'm receiving is:

```
**"CASE" is not valid in this position, expecting "SET"**
```

Here is the the stored procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`statements`@`%` procedure `SetWorksheetCat` ()
BEGIN
UPDATE statements.trans t
CASE t
WHEN t.OurBank = BOAUSD1234 & t.BankTranCode In(171, 491,481) THEN SET t.WorkSheetCatCodeTest = 'CAT 1'
WHEN t.OurBank = BOAUSD1234 & t.BankTranCode In(699) & t.Comments like %ISI OPERATING% THEN SET t.WorkSheetCatCodeTest = 'CAT 2'
WHEN t.OurBank = BOAUSD1234 & t.BankTranCode In(495) & t.Comments like %ISI OPERATING% THEN SET t.WorkSheetCatCodeTest = 'CAT 3'
WHEN t.OurBank = BOAUSD1234 & t.BankTranCode In(481) & t.Comments like %INT-DEBT% THEN SET t.WorkSheetCatCodeTest = 'CAT 4'
ELSE SET t.WorkSheetCatCodeTest = 'NO MAPPING RULE'
END
```

Comment: `... statements.trans t set t.WorkSheetCatCodeTest = case ...`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to JEFF HOLT, I see my errors.

1. Need to replace case t with set t.WorkSheetCatCodeTest = case
2. Need to replace each one of these BOAUSD1234 with `BOAUSD1234`
3. Neet to replace END with END;
4. Need to Add final END to the Proc